# Do something if location.hash is equal to some value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash

I have a function called Designer and I want to return this function if location.hash equals isDesign. I tried the following...

```
function Designer() {
  $("#boxA").fadeIn(700);
  $("#boxA span#closeControl").on("click",function(){
   $("#builderBox").fadeOut(700);
  });
}
if (location.hash = "isDesign") {
return Designer();
}
```

Instead of the function executing, it assigns the isDesign hash to the url and reloads the page several times. Please, what should I do to correct this. All answers will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The Designer-function does not return anything, do you simply want to call it if the hash matches? Also the hash, I believe, would be "#isDesign" would it not?

Comment: Yes, but it is still not working. I tried to call an alert instead of returning the function but it did not work.

Comment: `if (location.hash = "isDesign")`

You're missing (at least) an = on this line. A single = is assigning a value to location.hash. Since you're comparing values, you need == (or === for strict typing).

Comment: The unsolved problem here is how to deal with URLencoding; e.g. `if (location.hash == '#'+id)` isn't quite right if e.g. `id == "HQ9+"`, because you'll find that `location.hash == "#HQ9%2B"` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#isDesign") {
        Designer();
    }
});

function Designer() {
    $("#boxA").fadeIn(700);
    $("#boxA span#closeControl").on("click",function(){
       $("#builderBox").fadeOut(700);
    });
}
```

or just

```
$(function() {
    if (location.hash === "#isDesign") {
        $("#boxA").fadeIn(700);
        $("#boxA span#closeControl").on("click",function(){
           $("#builderBox").fadeOut(700);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much. this is the answer to my question. Everything is fine now.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can accept the answer, so this question will be "closed".

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (location.hash == "isDesign") {
    return Designer();
}
```

Single `=` is assignment, double `==` is comparison

Comment: Thanks very mush. I tried it but the function is not working. Is it a problem with my function

Comment: Do you have jQuery included? Try to move the code to a `$(function() { /* Your code here */ });` and see if that helps.

Comment: Yes jQuery is included. I will try that.

Comment: `location.hash` returns the hash value with `'#'`.

Comment: @Peter when i used the assignment operator, the function was running but the  the page kept on reloading. When tried the comparison nothing worked at all.